# Running on my laptop, but giving runtime error on Leetcode

Tags: c++, tree, inorder

I have to build a tree from preorder and inorder traversals. The code is working fine on my laptop, but not on leetcode. It is giving runtime error, any suggestions ?

```
int findindex(vector<int>& inorder,int index) {
    int size = inorder.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(index == inorder[i])
                return index;
    } }

TreeNode* helper(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder, int start, int end) {
    static int preindex = 0;
    if(start > end)
        return NULL;
    TreeNode* head;
    head = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    head->val = preorder[preindex++];
    head->left = NULL;
    head->right = NULL;
    if(start == end)
        return head;
    int index = findindex(inorder,head->val);

    head->left = helper(preorder, inorder,start, index-1);
    head ->right = helper(preorder, inorder, index+1, end);
    return head; }

TreeNode* Solution::buildTree(vector<int> &preorder, vector<int> &inorder) {
    int size = preorder.size();
    if(size == 0)
        return NULL;
    return helper(preorder, inorder, 0, size-1); }
```

Comment: well, it prints my phone number on my palmtop!!!

Comment: `findindex` may return unknown thing if no element in `inorder` is the same as `index` and it may be bad.

Comment: @NathanOliver so that i know the index of the node(which will start from head).

Comment: @MikeCAT It is guaranteed that the element will be present.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ assignment ?

Comment: @PaulR No particular reason, but  practise, but i dont think error will be due to that ?

Comment: post the TreeNode struct/class declaration too and if possible, Solution class too.

Comment: @nikhilgarg89: it's not a great idea, but whether it's a problem or not depends on whether `TreeNode` is a class or just POD - we can't tell because you haven't told us.

Comment: TreeNode is just a struct

Comment: This is not a [mcve].